# ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim doesn't exist

Tags: neovim

I am trying to install a config for Neovim and one of the installation steps requires that I install to ~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim. However, I don't see a nvim folder in /AppData/Local, only nvim-data. Anyone know why and how to fix? I installed Neovim with scoop by the way.

Comment: Just create  directory `~/AppData/Local/nvim/` and put your `init.vim` there.

Answer (score 0):

Neovim doesn't come with a nvim folder in appdata, if you can't cd into it run the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd %appdata%\..\Local\
mkdir nvim
explorer nvim
```